# WebDAV standalone server (HttpListener) : Mapping with Windows Explorer impossible

Tags: vb.net, webdav, windows-explorer, httplistener

I'm currently developing a WebDAV server in VB.NET. The server I'm trying to build should be standalone, so no IIS, nor Apache,...
I'm using the HttpListener class to wait for HTTP/WebDAV requests.
The server will be used to map files/folders that are contained in a SQL Server DB.

I tried to map a simple local folder to the Windows Explorer (as a network drive) with IIS, and with Apache, and it works "out of the box". But when I try to map my own WebDAV server to the Windows Explorer as a network drive, Windows says it's not a valid folder...

My server receives 3 requests from the Windows Explorer : OPTIONS, PROPFIND, and again PROPFIND.
The server sends a response to all these requests, and if I snif the network traffic with RawCap, I can't see anything wrong in the XML response, nor in the HTTP headers...
I also sniffed the traffic when I tried with IIS or Apache, and there were a few differences, which I tried to correct, but nothing made a difference, the server is still not working as a network drive in Windows Explorer...

I also compared my code to other open-source WebDAV servers, but I can't figure out why it is not working...

I also tried to take the XML sent as a response from IIS or Apache, and to send it with my server, without success.

So, are there any specific things to implement to make it work with the Windows Explorer ?
Maybe I forgot a little thing that's needed, maybe someone can help me out...

The main code :

```
Module WebServer

#Region "Main"
    Sub Main()
        Dim prefixes(0) As String
        prefixes(0) = "http://*:80/"
        ProcessRequests(prefixes)
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Request processing"

    Private Sub HandleRequest(context As HttpListenerContext)
        Dim sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = Nothing
        Dim requestHandler As IMethodHandler = Nothing


        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss} >>> ", DateTime.Now) + context.Request.HttpMethod + " Request from : " + context.Request.UserAgent)
        Console.WriteLine("    KeepAlive: {0}", context.Request.KeepAlive)
        Console.WriteLine("    Local end point: {0}", context.Request.LocalEndPoint.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("    Remote end point: {0}", context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("    Is local? {0}", context.Request.IsLocal)
        Console.WriteLine("    HTTP method: {0}", context.Request.HttpMethod)
        Console.WriteLine("    Protocol version: {0}", context.Request.ProtocolVersion)
        Console.WriteLine("    Is authenticated: {0}", context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        Console.WriteLine("    Is secure: {0}", context.Request.IsSecureConnection)

        ' Create the response
        response = context.Response

        response.ContentType = "text/xml"
        response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

        ' User authentication
        'Dim identity As HttpListenerBasicIdentity = context.User.Identity

        'If Not identity.Name.Equals("test") Or Not identity.Password.Equals("test") Then
        'response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
        'response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=""Server""")

        'Else
        Select Case context.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper()
            Case "OPTIONS"
                requestHandler = New OPTIONS_Handler(context)
            Case "GET"
                requestHandler = New GET_Handler(context)
            Case "HEAD"
                requestHandler = New HEAD_Handler(context)
            Case "PUT"
                requestHandler = New PUT_Handler(context)
            Case "POST"
                requestHandler = New POST_Handler(context)
            Case "DELETE"
                requestHandler = New DELETE_Handler(context)
            Case "COPY"
                requestHandler = New COPY_Handler(context)
            Case "MOVE"
                requestHandler = New MOVE_Handler(context)
            Case "MKCOL"
                requestHandler = New MKCOL_Handler(context)
            Case "PROPFIND"
                requestHandler = New PROPFIND_Handler(context)
            Case "PROPPATCH"
                requestHandler = New PROPPATCH_Handler(context)
            Case Else
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown Command")
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented
        End Select

        If Not requestHandler Is Nothing Then
            requestHandler.processRequest()
        End If

        If response IsNot Nothing Then
            response.Close()
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Time : {0}", sw.Elapsed)
        'End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessRequests(ByVal prefixes() As String)
        If Not System.Net.HttpListener.IsSupported Then
            Console.WriteLine( _
                "Windows XP SP2, Server 2003, or higher is required to " & _
                "use the HttpListener class.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' URI prefixes are required
        If prefixes Is Nothing OrElse prefixes.Length = 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("prefixes")
        End If

        ' Create a listener and add the prefixes
        Dim listener As System.Net.HttpListener = New System.Net.HttpListener()
        For Each s As String In prefixes
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s)
        Next

        Try
            ' Start the listener to begin listening for requests and set authentication
            'listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic
            listener.Start()
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...")

            While True
               Try
                    ' Note: GetContext blocks while waiting for a request
                    Dim context As HttpListenerContext = listener.GetContext()
                    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub() HandleRequest(context))
                    t.Start()

                Catch ex As HttpListenerException
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End While

        Catch ex As HttpListenerException
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Stop listening for requests
            listener.Close()
            Console.WriteLine("Done Listening...")
        End Try
    End Sub
#End Region

End Module
```

The OPTIONS handler :

```
Public Class OPTIONS_Handler : Implements IMethodHandler

    Private context As HttpListenerContext
    Private response As HttpListenerResponse

    Public Sub New(ByVal ctxt As HttpListenerContext)
        context = ctxt
        response = context.Response
    End Sub

    Public Sub processRequest() Implements IMethodHandler.processRequest
        response.AppendHeader("Allow", "OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, COPY, MOVE, MKCOL, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH")
        response.AppendHeader("Public", "OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, COPY, MOVE, MKCOL, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH")
        response.AppendHeader("DAV", "1, 2, ordered-collections")
        response.AppendHeader("Versioning-Support", "DAV:basicversioning")
        response.AppendHeader("MS-Author-Via", "DAV")
        'response.AppendHeader("X_MSDAVEXT", "1")
        'response.AppendHeader("Translate", "f")

        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the PROPFIND handler :

```
Public Class PROPFIND_Handler : Implements IMethodHandler

    Private context As HttpListenerContext
    Private response As HttpListenerResponse

    Public Sub New(ByVal ctxt As HttpListenerContext)
        context = ctxt
        response = context.Response
    End Sub

    Public Sub processRequest() Implements IMethodHandler.processRequest
        Try
            context.Response.SendChunked = False

            ' Check if the XML request is valid and well-formed
            Dim request As HttpListenerRequest = context.Request
            Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(request.InputStream)

            ' See if the inputstream includes some data. If not --> Exception
            Dim buffer(16 * 1024) As Byte
            Dim read As Integer
            Dim memstr As New MemoryStream

            While (read = request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
                memstr.Write(buffer, 0, read)
            End While

            If memstr.Length <> 0 Then
                Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(reader)
            End If

            response.StatusCode = 207
            Dim xmlWriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter("test.xml", New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False))
            'xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

            xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("D:multistatus")
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:D", "DAV:")
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:b", "urn:uuid:c2f41010-65b3-11d1-a29f-00aa00c14882")

            ' Get the requested URI
            Dim requestedURI As String = context.Request.Url.LocalPath

            ' Get the files and folders list from the mapped folder
            Dim mappedFolderInfo
            If requestedURI.Equals("/") Then
                mappedFolderInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo("MappedFolder")
            Else
                mappedFolderInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo("MappedFolder" + requestedURI)
            End If

            Dim filesList As IO.FileInfo() = mappedFolderInfo.GetFiles()
            Dim foldersList As IO.DirectoryInfo() = mappedFolderInfo.GetDirectories()

            ' List all the files and folders and build the corresponding XML response
            Dim tempFile As IO.FileInfo
            Dim tempFolder As IO.DirectoryInfo
            For Each tempFolder In foldersList
                Dim webDavItem As New WebDAVItem()
                webDavItem.CollectionYN = True
                webDavItem.ContentLength = 0
                webDavItem.CreationDate = tempFolder.CreationTime
                webDavItem.LastModifDate = tempFolder.LastWriteTime
                webDavItem.Name = tempFolder.Name + "/"
                webDavItem.Path = requestedURI
                webDavItem.BuildXmlResponse(xmlWriter)
            Next
            For Each tempFile In filesList
                Dim webDavItem As New WebDAVItem()
                webDavItem.CollectionYN = False
                webDavItem.ContentLength = tempFile.Length
                webDavItem.CreationDate = tempFile.CreationTime
                webDavItem.LastModifDate = tempFile.LastWriteTime
                webDavItem.Name = tempFile.Name
                webDavItem.Path = requestedURI
                webDavItem.BuildXmlResponse(xmlWriter)
            Next

            xmlWriter.Close()


            Dim f As FileStream = File.OpenRead("test.xml")
            Dim fileData(f.Length) As Byte

            response.ContentLength64 = f.Length
            f.Read(fileData, 0, f.Length)
            f.Close()

            response.OutputStream.Write(fileData, 0, response.ContentLength64)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Exception while handling PROPFIND : " + ex.Message)
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is partially solved.

It seemed to be the creationdate, in the response XML, that wasn't in the right format. The format was right, but there was a 'Z' letter missing at the end of the date string... Don't ask why, I don't know :)

I hard-coded the letter, and the Windows Explorer accepted to map the server as a network drive.
There are still some mistakes, when the Explorer tries to retrieve the content of the mapped folder, but it shouldn't be too difficult to correct them.

EDIT : the problem is now completely solved. It was just a NullRefException that occured during a PROPFIND. Everything is now fine.